# recode related values in an efficient way

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have a dataframe `df` with only one variable `var` with some related values.

```
df <- data.frame(var = c(rep('AUS',12), rep('NZ',12), rep('ENG',7), rep('SOC',12), 
                            rep('PAK',11), rep('SRI',17), rep('IND',15)))

df %>% count(var)
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#      var     n
#   <fctr> <int>
# 1    AUS    12
# 2    ENG     7
# 3    IND    15
# 4     NZ    12
# 5    PAK    11
# 6    SOC    12
# 7    SRI    17
```

Based on some relations, some values should be recoded with a new value.

```
df %>% mutate(var = recode(var, 'AUS' = 'A', 'NZ' = 'A', 'ENG' = 'A', 
                           'SOC' = 'A', 'PAK' = 'B', 'SRI' = 'B')) %>% count(var)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      var     n
#   <fctr> <int>
# 1      A    43
# 2    IND    15
# 3      B    28
```

It can be seen that `A`  and `B` recodes for 4 and 2 values respectively. I have also the expected solution in the question. However, is there any other efficient way to do this, instead of specifying the relations same number of times(4,2)??

Comment: Something like `replace(var, var %in% to_change_A, 'A')` and respectively for B?

Comment: Looks like you have a custom list to recode.  Try with `case_when` i.e. `df %>% mutate(var = as.character(var), var =case_when(var %in% c('AUS', 'NZ', 'ENG', 'SOC') ~ 'A', var %in% c('PAK', 'SRI') ~ 'B', TRUE ~var))`

Comment: Alternatively, convert replace list to a `data.frame` and do a merge/join.

Comment: Did you mean to keep IND unchanged?  Or should IND get a code too?

Comment: @G5W yes.. (atleast for now).

Comment: Sotos, akrun, mt1022 thanks for your ideas. I will do that.

Comment: In base R, probably easiest / most efficient is `levels(df$var)[levels(df$var) %in% c('AUS', 'NZ', 'ENG', 'SOC')] <- 'A'` and similar for B.

Comment: @Sotos Tried: `df %>% mutate(var = replace(var, var %in% c('AUS','NZ','ENG','SOC'), "A"))  %>% count(var)`  Error: `4     NA    43` Warning:`Warning message:In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "A") :  invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: Make `var` a character. You get the warning because It's a factor. So something like `df %>% mutate(var = as.character(var), var = replace(var, var %in% c('AUS','NZ','ENG','SOC'), "A")) %>% count(var)` should work

Comment: @Sotos Thanks it worked. For  recoding to `B`, I have to provide another replace command. Is there any way which could achieve both in a single command?

Comment: Single way being that you will not have to call `replace` twice? Because separating `A`s from `B`s is a two line job anyway

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a vector with named entries as a lookup table.

```
Codes = c(rep('A', 4), rep('B', 2), 'IND') 
names(Codes) = c('AUS', 'NZ', 'ENG', 'SOC', 'PAK', 'SRI', 'IND')
df$var = Codes[as.character(df$var)]
```