# Recode a string column into integer using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

How to create a new integer column `recode` which recodes for an existing column `y` in the dataframe `df` using `dplyr` approaches?

```
# Generates Random data 
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50), 
                 y = sample(LETTERS, 50, replace = TRUE), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Structure of the data
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 50 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ x: int  90 4 33 85 30 19 78 77 7 10 ...
# $ y: chr  "N" "B" "P" "W" ...

# Making the character vector as factor variable
df$y <- factor(df$y)

# Structure of the data to llok at the effect of factor creation
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 50 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ x: int  90 4 33 85 30 19 78 77 7 10 ...
# $ y: Factor w/ 23 levels "A","B","C","E",..: 12 2 14 21 12 22 7 1 6 17 ...

# collecting the levels of the factor variable
labs <- levels(df$y)

# Recode the levels to sequential integers
recode <- 1:length(labs)

# Creates the recode dataframe
dfrecode <- data.frame(labs, recode)

# Mapping the recodes to the original data
df$recode <- dfrecode[match(df$y, dfrecode$labs), 'recode']
```

This code works as expected. But I want to replace this approach with a dplyr or other efficient approaches. I can achieve the same using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46527758/4836511) if I know all the values. But I would like to do this without seeing or explicitly listing the values present in the column

Comment: `dplyr::recode()` ?

Comment: Should not we need to explicitly mention all the values present for using `dplyr::recode()` function?

Comment: The `fct_anon` from the `forcats` package can be useful?

Comment: Do you strictly need sequential integers?

Comment: what about `as.numeric(df$y)`?

Comment: `fct_anon` is one approach. But I prefer sequential as per my current approach. If no other way is possible, I could use this, besides finding a way to use this in dplyr pipe along with `as.factor()`.

Comment: `as.numeric(as.factor(df$y))` can be used. But how to use in `dplyr` setting?

Comment: you can always use it inside of `dplyr::mutate()` if you want to, if its easy in base R why add dependencies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick here is that doing `as.numeric(factor)` actually returns the levels as integers. So, try this

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50), 
                 y = sample(LETTERS, 50, replace = TRUE), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
dfrecode <- df %>%
        mutate(recode = as.numeric(factor(y)))
str(dfrecode)
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to include `df$y <- factor(df$y)` in the pipe? This was the major hurdle which I did not get worked.

Comment: I think you don't need to include it, you can just mutate on `factor(y)`. I edited my answer.